# Problems getting user created method to show in properties dialogue

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Problems getting user created method to show in properties dialogue
So I've created the most basic textbox and added it to a winform.
I can see the _key and _value but the method does not show :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace testTextbox
{
    public class myTextbox : TextBox
    {
        public string _key { get; set; }
        public string _value { get; set; }
        public void aa()
        {
// aa does not appear in the properties dialogue when the text box is on the form
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are not shown in the property grid, only properties and events are shown.

Comment: Well, that promptly ends this question.